# How to add custom button instead of copy button in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I am creating an app. In that app, I have phrase of text which is generated by small chunk of text. Now when user touch on that text then specific chunk of text will highlighted and it will display custom button on top of text in stead of copy. So how can I do that?

Here what I have tried. I have put mu text in textview and make textview editable no, so keyboard will not be shown and I can get selected text. if you have any other better way to achieve this then please suggest.

```
UITextView * resionTV = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 224, 190, 90)];
    resionTV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    resionTV.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
    resionTV.text = xstr;
    resionTV.editable = NO;
   // resionTV.delegate = self;
    resionTV.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [self.view addSubview:resionTV];
```

And this code i have get from apple developer site, but not sure it is what i am looking for, and it will do nothing so also help here.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([theTouch tapCount] == 2) {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
        UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change Color" action:@selector(changeColor:)];
        UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menuCont setTargetRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50) inView:self.view];
        menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowLeft;
        menuCont.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem];
        [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

[image: Screenshot of text highlight]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement in my project; But, was unable to find out, *how to customize the appearance of the MenuItem in iOS?*

AFAIK, You [***can create the custom menu***](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html) but *cannot customize the appearance* of it. It will look like the native iOS menu with the custom item you have added.

Hope this will lead you some where.

Comment: @Ping Let me know *if this answer helped you OR NOT* by accepting, If not than better I should *delete* it.